# "Make New Folder" on a Microsoft Shell.Application.BrowseForFolder window - doesn't rename the folder on the filesystem

Tags: windows, shell, vbscript, wsh

So I have the following code to wrap the Shell.Application.BrowseForFolder() method.  It's adapted from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/17/how-can-i-show-users-a-dialog-box-that-only-lets-them-select-folders.aspx:

```
Function BrowseFolder( myStartLocation, blnSimpleDialog, strPrompt )
    Const MY_COMPUTER   = &H11&
    Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0 ' Must ALWAYS be 0

    Dim numOptions, objFolder, objFolderItem
    Dim objPath, objShell, strPath ', strPrompt

    ' Set the options for the dialog window
    'strPrompt = "Select a folder:"
    If blnSimpleDialog = True Then
        numOptions = 0      ' Simple dialog
    Else
        numOptions = &H10&  ' Additional text field to type folder path
    End If

    ' Create a Windows Shell object
    Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    ' If specified, convert "My Computer" to a valid
    ' path for the Windows Shell's BrowseFolder method
    If UCase( myStartLocation ) = "MY COMPUTER" Then
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace( MY_COMPUTER )
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
        strPath = objFolderItem.Path
    Else
        strPath = myStartLocation
    End If

    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( WINDOW_HANDLE, strPrompt, _
                                              numOptions, strPath )

    ' Quit if no folder was selected
    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        BrowseFolder = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Retrieve the path of the selected folder
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path

    ' Return the path of the selected folder
    BrowseFolder = objPath
End Function
```

Here is the code that calls it:

```
Function GetSLOCDir()
   Dim FSO
   Dim slocDir
   Dim cwd

   Set FSO    = GetFSO()

   slocDir = ""
   While (slocDir="" OR NOT FSO.FolderExists(slocDir))
      cwd        = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
      slocDir    = BrowseFolder(cwd, True, "Select the SLOC Directory.")
      WScript.Echo "slocDir: " & slocDir

      If (slocDir="") Then
         WScript.Echo "Aborted."
         WScript.Quit
      End If

   WEnd
   GetSLOCDir = slocDir
End Function
```

The first time through the loop, the browse dialog is displayed.  If I click "Make New Folder", it creates a new folder, allowing me to type a folder name.  But when I press enter, it goes back to saying "New Folder", but on the filesystem it renames it correctly.  However, the BrowseFolder() function returns "New Folder", which causes the loop to iterate.  The new browse dialog shows the correct folder name, which I can then select.

However this seems clunky.  Is this a bug in the BrowseForFolder method?

Thanks

Comment: Never have such problem. Is this appear under concrete Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my English first.
You can run this script using cscript.exe or 64bit-Version of wscript.exe.
32bit Version has this bug.